# C# Dynamic Dictionary

Tags: generics, c#-3.0

I would like to find a way to have a Dictionary of various Mock objects with their various instances keyed by some kind of unique identifier. I am using Moq, so the syntax for that is `Mock<IFoo>` as far as the typing goes. But I would like to have the Dictionary contain basically this so I can dynamically resolve and overwrite instances at runtime:

```
Key = IFoo (basically a type)

Value = new SomeCustomType< T >
{
  T ConcreteObject
  Mock< T > MockObject
}
```

I may not be getting my question across appropriately but I could use some help!

Comment: What would the keys and values be, exactly, and what would they be used for? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "Key = IFoo". An interface isn't an object, and it certainly isn't going to be a unique key if you use it everywhere.

Comment: I think the Key would be an instance of Type. So maybe an example would be typeof(IFoo). 

The value would be an instance of a concrete object of that type and a mock object of that type.

Comment: It seems you're trying to reinvent something similar to the automocking container, but what do you want the concrete object for?

Comment: Good point. I may not need the concrete object and I am trying to implement a form of automocking. What automocking container are you speaking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the concrete object you could use an [automocking container](http://blog.eleutian.com/CommentView,guid,762249da-e25a-4503-8f20-c6d59b1a69bc.aspx).

[Here's an Autofac automocking container for Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but here's my take.  If you want a dictionary of instances keyed by type, the easiest way to do that is to use a static generic class rather than an actual dictionary:

```
public static class Dict<T> {
    public static T Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to set the instance associated with type `IFoo` you would do `Dict<IFoo>.Instance = myIFooInstance;`, and to get it back out you'd just store the result of `Dict<IFoo>.Instance`.

If instead, you want to get out `Mock` instances keyed by types, you could do something very similar:

```
public static class MockDict<T> {
    public static Mock<T> Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can do something along the lines of:

```
Mock<IFoo> myMock = ...
MockDict<IFoo>.Instance = myMock;
...
Mock<IFoo> myMock2 = MockDict<IFoo>.Instance;
```